# I need help with installing Ubuntu

Tags: system-installation

I got an error message to see a log. I read the log and I don't understand it.

Here it is:

```
04-24 17:48 INFO   root: === wubi 14.04 rev286 ===
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  root: Logfile is c:\users\katrina\appdata\local\temp\wubi-14.04-rev286.log
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  root: sys.argv = ['main.pyo', '--exefile="C:\\Users\\Katrina\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\7zOADDB.tmp\\wubi.exe"']
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  CommonBackend: data_dir=C:\Users\Katrina\AppData\Local\Temp\pylB963.tmp\data
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: 7z=C:\Users\Katrina\AppData\Local\Temp\pylB963.tmp\bin\7z.exe
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: startup_folder=C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Fetching basic info...
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  CommonBackend: original_exe=C:\Users\Katrina\AppData\Local\Temp\7zOADDB.tmp\wubi.exe
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  CommonBackend: platform=win32
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  CommonBackend: osname=nt
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  CommonBackend: language=en_US
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  CommonBackend: encoding=cp1252
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: arch=amd64
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Parsing isolist=C:\Users\Katrina\AppData\Local\Temp\pylB963.tmp\data\isolist.ini
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Edubuntu-i386
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Kubuntu-amd64
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Mythbuntu-i386
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Edubuntu-amd64
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Ubuntu Studio-amd64
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Ubuntu-amd64
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Lubuntu-i386
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Ubuntu-i386
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Mythbuntu-amd64
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Kubuntu-i386
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Ubuntu Studio-i386
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Lubuntu-amd64
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: Fetching host info...
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: registry_key=Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Wubi
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: windows version=vista
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: windows_version2=Windows 8.1
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: windows_sp=None
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: windows_build=9600
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: gmt=-5
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: country=US
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: timezone=America/New_York
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: windows_username=Katrina
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: user_full_name=Katrina
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: user_directory=C:\Users\Katrina
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: windows_language_code=1033
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: windows_language=English
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: processor_name=Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-4030U CPU @ 1.90GHz
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: bootloader=vista
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: system_drive=Drive(C: hd 662650.480469 mb free ntfs)
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: drive=Drive(C: hd 662650.480469 mb free ntfs)
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: drive=Drive(D: hd 1974.08984375 mb free ntfs)
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: drive=Drive(E: cd 0.0 mb free )
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: uninstaller_path=None
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: previous_target_dir=None
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: previous_distro_name=None
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: keyboard_id=67699721
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: keyboard_layout=us
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: keyboard_variant=
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  CommonBackend: python locale=('en_US', 'cp1252')
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  CommonBackend: locale=en_US.UTF-8
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: total_memory_mb=4095.99999905
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Searching ISOs on USB devices
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Searching for local CDs
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\Katrina\AppData\Local\Temp\pylB963.tmp is a valid Ubuntu CD
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\Katrina\AppData\Local\Temp\pylB963.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\Katrina\AppData\Local\Temp\pylB963.tmp is a valid Ubuntu CD
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\Katrina\AppData\Local\Temp\pylB963.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\Katrina\AppData\Local\Temp\pylB963.tmp is a valid Kubuntu CD
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\Katrina\AppData\Local\Temp\pylB963.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\Katrina\AppData\Local\Temp\pylB963.tmp is a valid Kubuntu CD
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\Katrina\AppData\Local\Temp\pylB963.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\Katrina\AppData\Local\Temp\pylB963.tmp is a valid Mythbuntu CD
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\Katrina\AppData\Local\Temp\pylB963.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\Katrina\AppData\Local\Temp\pylB963.tmp is a valid Mythbuntu CD
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\Katrina\AppData\Local\Temp\pylB963.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\Katrina\AppData\Local\Temp\pylB963.tmp is a valid Edubuntu CD
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\Katrina\AppData\Local\Temp\pylB963.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\Katrina\AppData\Local\Temp\pylB963.tmp is a valid Edubuntu CD
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\Katrina\AppData\Local\Temp\pylB963.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\Katrina\AppData\Local\Temp\pylB963.tmp is a valid Lubuntu CD
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\Katrina\AppData\Local\Temp\pylB963.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\Katrina\AppData\Local\Temp\pylB963.tmp is a valid Lubuntu CD
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\Katrina\AppData\Local\Temp\pylB963.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\Katrina\AppData\Local\Temp\pylB963.tmp is a valid Ubuntu Studio CD
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\Katrina\AppData\Local\Temp\pylB963.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\Katrina\AppData\Local\Temp\pylB963.tmp is a valid Ubuntu Studio CD
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\Katrina\AppData\Local\Temp\pylB963.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Ubuntu CD
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Ubuntu CD
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Kubuntu CD
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Kubuntu CD
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Mythbuntu CD
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Mythbuntu CD
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Edubuntu CD
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Edubuntu CD
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Lubuntu CD
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Lubuntu CD
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Ubuntu Studio CD
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Ubuntu Studio CD
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether E:\ is a valid Ubuntu CD
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain E:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether E:\ is a valid Ubuntu CD
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain E:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether E:\ is a valid Kubuntu CD
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain E:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether E:\ is a valid Kubuntu CD
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain E:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether E:\ is a valid Mythbuntu CD
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain E:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether E:\ is a valid Mythbuntu CD
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain E:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether E:\ is a valid Edubuntu CD
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain E:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether E:\ is a valid Edubuntu CD
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain E:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether E:\ is a valid Lubuntu CD
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain E:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether E:\ is a valid Lubuntu CD
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain E:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether E:\ is a valid Ubuntu Studio CD
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain E:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether E:\ is a valid Ubuntu Studio CD
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain E:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
04-24 17:48 INFO   root: Running the installer...
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  WindowsFrontend: __init__...
04-24 17:48 DEBUG  WindowsFrontend: on_init...
04-24 17:48 INFO   WinuiPage: appname=wubi, localedir=C:\Users\Katrina\AppData\Local\Temp\pylB963.tmp\translations, languages=['en_US', 'en']
04-24 17:48 INFO   WinuiPage: appname=wubi, localedir=C:\Users\Katrina\AppData\Local\Temp\pylB963.tmp\translations, languages=['en_US', 'en']
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  WinuiInstallationPage: target_drive=C:, installation_size=18000MB, distro_name=Ubuntu, language=en_US, locale=en_US.UTF-8, username=katrina
04-24 17:49 INFO   root: Received settings
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Searching for local CD
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\Katrina\AppData\Local\Temp\pylB963.tmp is a valid Ubuntu CD
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\Katrina\AppData\Local\Temp\pylB963.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Ubuntu CD
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether E:\ is a valid Ubuntu CD
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain E:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Searching for local ISO
04-24 17:49 INFO   WinuiPage: appname=wubi, localedir=C:\Users\Katrina\AppData\Local\Temp\pylB963.tmp\translations, languages=['en_US', 'en']
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  TaskList: # Running tasklist...
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Running select_target_dir...
04-24 17:49 INFO   WindowsBackend: Installing into C:\ubuntu
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Finished select_target_dir
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Running create_dir_structure...
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Creating dir C:\ubuntu
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Creating dir C:\ubuntu\disks
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Creating dir C:\ubuntu\install
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Creating dir C:\ubuntu\install\boot
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Creating dir C:\ubuntu\disks\boot
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Creating dir C:\ubuntu\disks\boot\grub
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Creating dir C:\ubuntu\install\boot\grub
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Finished create_dir_structure
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Running uncompress_target_dir...
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Finished uncompress_target_dir
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Running create_uninstaller...
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: Copying uninstaller C:\Users\Katrina\AppData\Local\Temp\7zOADDB.tmp\wubi.exe -> C:\ubuntu\uninstall-wubi.exe
04-24 17:49 ERROR  TaskList: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Katrina\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\7zOADDB.tmp\\wubi.exe'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\tasklist.py", line 197, in __call__
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\win32\backend.py", line 116, in create_uninstaller
  File "\lib\shutil.py", line 38, in copyfile
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Katrina\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\7zOADDB.tmp\\wubi.exe'
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  TaskList: # Cancelling tasklist
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  TaskList: # Finished tasklist
04-24 17:49 ERROR  root: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Katrina\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\7zOADDB.tmp\\wubi.exe'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 58, in run
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 132, in select_task
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 158, in run_installer
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\tasklist.py", line 197, in __call__
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\win32\backend.py", line 116, in create_uninstaller
  File "\lib\shutil.py", line 38, in copyfile
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Katrina\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\7zOADDB.tmp\\wubi.exe'
04-24 17:49 INFO   root: === wubi 14.04 rev286 ===
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  root: Logfile is c:\users\katrina\appdata\local\temp\wubi-14.04-rev286.log
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  root: sys.argv = ['main.pyo', '--exefile="C:\\Users\\Katrina\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\7zO3E64.tmp\\wubi.exe"']
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  CommonBackend: data_dir=C:\Users\Katrina\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl4DF2.tmp\data
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: 7z=C:\Users\Katrina\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl4DF2.tmp\bin\7z.exe
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: startup_folder=C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Fetching basic info...
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  CommonBackend: original_exe=C:\Users\Katrina\AppData\Local\Temp\7zO3E64.tmp\wubi.exe
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  CommonBackend: platform=win32
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  CommonBackend: osname=nt
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  CommonBackend: language=en_US
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  CommonBackend: encoding=cp1252
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: arch=amd64
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Parsing isolist=C:\Users\Katrina\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl4DF2.tmp\data\isolist.ini
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Edubuntu-i386
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Kubuntu-amd64
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Mythbuntu-i386
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Edubuntu-amd64
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Ubuntu Studio-amd64
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Ubuntu-amd64
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Lubuntu-i386
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Ubuntu-i386
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Mythbuntu-amd64
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Kubuntu-i386
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Ubuntu Studio-i386
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Lubuntu-amd64
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: Fetching host info...
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: registry_key=Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Wubi
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: windows version=vista
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: windows_version2=Windows 8.1
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: windows_sp=None
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: windows_build=9600
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: gmt=-5
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: country=US
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: timezone=America/New_York
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: windows_username=Katrina
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: user_full_name=Katrina
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: user_directory=C:\Users\Katrina
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: windows_language_code=1033
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: windows_language=English
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: processor_name=Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-4030U CPU @ 1.90GHz
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: bootloader=vista
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: system_drive=Drive(C: hd 662647.066406 mb free ntfs)
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: drive=Drive(C: hd 662647.066406 mb free ntfs)
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: drive=Drive(D: hd 1974.08984375 mb free ntfs)
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: drive=Drive(E: cd 0.0 mb free )
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: uninstaller_path=None
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: previous_target_dir=None
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: previous_distro_name=None
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: keyboard_id=67699721
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: keyboard_layout=us
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: keyboard_variant=
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  CommonBackend: python locale=('en_US', 'cp1252')
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  CommonBackend: locale=en_US.UTF-8
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: total_memory_mb=4095.99999905
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Searching ISOs on USB devices
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Searching for local CDs
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\Katrina\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl4DF2.tmp is a valid Ubuntu CD
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\Katrina\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl4DF2.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\Katrina\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl4DF2.tmp is a valid Ubuntu CD
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\Katrina\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl4DF2.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\Katrina\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl4DF2.tmp is a valid Kubuntu CD
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\Katrina\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl4DF2.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\Katrina\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl4DF2.tmp is a valid Kubuntu CD
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\Katrina\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl4DF2.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\Katrina\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl4DF2.tmp is a valid Mythbuntu CD
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\Katrina\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl4DF2.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\Katrina\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl4DF2.tmp is a valid Mythbuntu CD
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\Katrina\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl4DF2.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\Katrina\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl4DF2.tmp is a valid Edubuntu CD
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\Katrina\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl4DF2.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\Katrina\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl4DF2.tmp is a valid Edubuntu CD
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\Katrina\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl4DF2.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\Katrina\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl4DF2.tmp is a valid Lubuntu CD
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\Katrina\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl4DF2.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\Katrina\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl4DF2.tmp is a valid Lubuntu CD
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\Katrina\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl4DF2.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\Katrina\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl4DF2.tmp is a valid Ubuntu Studio CD
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\Katrina\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl4DF2.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\Katrina\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl4DF2.tmp is a valid Ubuntu Studio CD
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\Katrina\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl4DF2.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Ubuntu CD
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Ubuntu CD
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Kubuntu CD
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Kubuntu CD
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Mythbuntu CD
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Mythbuntu CD
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Edubuntu CD
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Edubuntu CD
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Lubuntu CD
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Lubuntu CD
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Ubuntu Studio CD
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Ubuntu Studio CD
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether E:\ is a valid Ubuntu CD
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain E:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether E:\ is a valid Ubuntu CD
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain E:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether E:\ is a valid Kubuntu CD
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain E:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether E:\ is a valid Kubuntu CD
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain E:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether E:\ is a valid Mythbuntu CD
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain E:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether E:\ is a valid Mythbuntu CD
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain E:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether E:\ is a valid Edubuntu CD
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain E:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether E:\ is a valid Edubuntu CD
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain E:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether E:\ is a valid Lubuntu CD
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain E:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether E:\ is a valid Lubuntu CD
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain E:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether E:\ is a valid Ubuntu Studio CD
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain E:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether E:\ is a valid Ubuntu Studio CD
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain E:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
04-24 17:49 INFO   root: Running the installer...
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  WindowsFrontend: __init__...
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  WindowsFrontend: on_init...
04-24 17:49 INFO   WinuiPage: appname=wubi, localedir=C:\Users\Katrina\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl4DF2.tmp\translations, languages=['en_US', 'en']
04-24 17:49 INFO   WinuiPage: appname=wubi, localedir=C:\Users\Katrina\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl4DF2.tmp\translations, languages=['en_US', 'en']
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  WinuiInstallationPage: target_drive=C:, installation_size=18000MB, distro_name=Ubuntu, language=en_US, locale=en_US.UTF-8, username=katrina
04-24 17:49 INFO   root: Received settings
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Searching for local CD
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\Katrina\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl4DF2.tmp is a valid Ubuntu CD
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\Katrina\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl4DF2.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Ubuntu CD
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether E:\ is a valid Ubuntu CD
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain E:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Searching for local ISO
04-24 17:49 INFO   WinuiPage: appname=wubi, localedir=C:\Users\Katrina\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl4DF2.tmp\translations, languages=['en_US', 'en']
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  TaskList: # Running tasklist...
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Running select_target_dir...
04-24 17:49 ERROR  TaskList: Cannot install into C:\ubuntu.
There is another file or directory with this name.
Please remove it before continuing.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\tasklist.py", line 197, in __call__
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\win32\backend.py", line 81, in select_target_dir
Exception: Cannot install into C:\ubuntu.
There is another file or directory with this name.
Please remove it before continuing.
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  TaskList: # Cancelling tasklist
04-24 17:49 DEBUG  TaskList: # Finished tasklist
04-24 17:49 ERROR  root: Cannot install into C:\ubuntu.
There is another file or directory with this name.
Please remove it before continuing.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 58, in run
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 132, in select_task
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 158, in run_installer
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\tasklist.py", line 197, in __call__
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\win32\backend.py", line 81, in select_target_dir
Exception: Cannot install into C:\ubuntu.
There is another file or directory with this name.
Please remove it before continuing.
04-24 18:06 INFO   root: === wubi 14.04 rev286 ===
04-24 18:06 DEBUG  root: Logfile is c:\users\katrina\appdata\local\temp\wubi-14.04-rev286.log
04-24 18:06 DEBUG  root: sys.argv = ['main.pyo', '--exefile="C:\\Users\\Katrina\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\7zOC701.tmp\\wubi.exe"']
04-24 18:06 DEBUG  CommonBackend: data_dir=C:\Users\Katrina\AppData\Local\Temp\pylD1B0.tmp\data
04-24 18:06 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: 7z=C:\Users\Katrina\AppData\Local\Temp\pylD1B0.tmp\bin\7z.exe
04-24 18:06 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: startup_folder=C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
04-24 18:06 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Fetching basic info...
04-24 18:06 DEBUG  CommonBackend: original_exe=C:\Users\Katrina\AppData\Local\Temp\7zOC701.tmp\wubi.exe
04-24 18:06 DEBUG  CommonBackend: platform=win32
04-24 18:06 DEBUG  CommonBackend: osname=nt
04-24 18:06 DEBUG  CommonBackend: language=en_US
04-24 18:06 DEBUG  CommonBackend: encoding=cp1252
04-24 18:06 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: arch=amd64
04-24 18:06 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Parsing isolist=C:\Users\Katrina\AppData\Local\Temp\pylD1B0.tmp\data\isolist.ini
04-24 18:06 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Edubuntu-i386
04-24 18:06 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Kubuntu-amd64
04-24 18:06 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Mythbuntu-i386
04-24 18:06 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Edubuntu-amd64
04-24 18:06 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Ubuntu Studio-amd64
04-24 18:06 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Ubuntu-amd64
04-24 18:06 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Lubuntu-i386
04-24 18:06 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Ubuntu-i386
04-24 18:06 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Mythbuntu-amd64
04-24 18:06 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Kubuntu-i386
04-24 18:06 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Ubuntu Studio-i386
04-24 18:06 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Lubuntu-amd64
04-24 18:06 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: Fetching host info...
04-24 18:06 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: registry_key=Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Wubi
04-24 18:06 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: windows version=vista
04-24 18:06 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: windows_version2=Windows 8.1
04-24 18:06 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: window
..."
```

Please help.

Comment: WUBI does not work with Windows 8 and above.

Comment: Installing Ubuntu on Windows 8 using WUBI doesn't work. 
See [the first answer to this question on Ask Ubuntu][1]. 


  [1]: https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported

Answer (score 0):

Wubi does not work on Windows 8 or higher. It only exists for 14.04 if you are using Windows 7 or previous. It has to do with bootloader differences. Canonical is no longer promoting Wubi has an optimal solution to install Ubuntu from within Windows (and thus, Wubi is hard to find if you don't know to look for it), and this is because more PCs ship with Windows 8 or higher now.

Additionally, there are concerns about filesystem integrity when running Ubuntu "inside" the Windows filesystem in this way.

I strongly suggest you install Ubuntu the normal way. The setup is extremely easy and will safely guide you through the entire dualboot process. Documentation on this process is also widely available.